# calculating loss and perplexity when evaluating GPT2 model even when not defined

Tags: python, nlp, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

When I'm trying to evaluate GPT2 model for text generation task, I printed loss and perplexity as given below in the code, but it is not defined in the code by me.

```
with torch.no_grad():

    for _ in range(length):
        outputs = model(generated)
        next_token_logits = outputs[0][:, -1, :] 
        next_token = torch.multinomial(F.softmax(next_token_logits, dim=-1), num_samples=1) 

        generated = torch.cat((generated, next_token), dim=1)

print(f"loss {loss}")
print(f"perplexity {perplexity}")

...
```

part from the output:

```
loss 3.644557237625122
perplexity 38.26582717895508
```

This prints out very realistic values for loss and perplexity and I'm not sure from where this is coming from, because if I change it to loss1 and perplexity1 it would give me this error

> ```
>      38 
> ---> 39 print(f"loss {loss1}")
>      40 print(f"perplexity {perplexity}")
>      41 
> NameError: name 'loss1' is not defined
> ```

Although here, for every generation, the loss and the perplexity will be the same.

So, I'm so confused as to how this is calculated automatically and would like some clarification since I'm very new to Pytorch and ML. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This seems like a pure Python issue. Are you running in a Jupyter notebook where you might have previously run some code that defined those variables?

Comment: @ziedaniel1, Yes, I'm using Google Colab's notebook. May be that's the reason since I train my model before this evaluation code.

Comment: You would need to paste the rest of the code for us to be able to help you. In the current code, we have neither the definition of loss or loss1, or perplexity for that matter